# How can I store my user input in a Driver to my variables in a Class?

Tags: java, oop

I'm still new to Stack and Java so let me clarify the question as best as I can. I'm currently learning OOP in Java and I have an assignment that requires us to create a voucher system where essentially the user inputs some information about a purchase, that information is assigned to a voucher, and then once paid the voucher is then assigned a check number.

Now, I have the Voucher Class set up and I believe it's set up correctly, but my issue is with the VoucherDriver. My VoucherDriver has all of the code for the user input, and my VoucherClass has all of my variables and my array for the vouchers themselves. Here is the VoucherClass code:

```
public class Voucher {

private static int nextVoucherNumber, nextCheckNumber;
private int _voucherNumber,_checkNumber;
private static Voucher[] vouchers;
private String _purchaseDate, _paymentDate, _debitAccount, _vendor;
private double _amount;

Voucher(String purchaseDate, double amount, String debitAccount, String vendor) {
    this._purchaseDate = purchaseDate;
    this._amount = amount;
    this._debitAccount = debitAccount;
    this._vendor = vendor;
    
    this._voucherNumber = nextVoucherNumber;
    //checks if the array is full
    for (int i = 0; i < vouchers.length; ++i) {
        if (vouchers[i] == null) {
            vouchers[i] = this;
            nextVoucherNumber++;
            break;
        }
    }
}

//must call this method first to initialize the vouchers
public static void initialize(int firstVoucher, int firstCheck, int maxNumberOfVouchers) {
    nextVoucherNumber = firstVoucher;
    nextCheckNumber = firstCheck;
    vouchers = new Voucher [maxNumberOfVouchers];
}

public static Voucher find(int voucherNumber) {
    for (Voucher v : vouchers) {
        if (v != null && v._voucherNumber == voucherNumber) {
            return v;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static void printData() {
    int count = 0;
    for (Voucher v : vouchers) {
        if (v != null) {
            System.out.println(v);
            count++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        //System.out.println("No Data.");
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Voucher #" + _voucherNumber + " Date: " + _purchaseDate + " Amount:$" + _amount + "\n" 
            + "Account: " + _debitAccount + " Vendor: " + _vendor + "\n" + "Check #:" + _checkNumber + " Date:" + _paymentDate + "\n";
}

public void issueCheck(String paymentDate) {
    this._paymentDate = paymentDate;
    this._checkNumber = nextCheckNumber;
    nextCheckNumber++;
    
}
```

}

How can I set the users input on the VoucherDriver, to equal a variable or method on the VoucherClass? Is that even possible or am I going in circles for no reason? I'll post some code snippets from my VoucherDriver below for extra clarification:

```
public class VoucherDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choiceSelection;
    Voucher.initialize(1001, 2001, 10);

    System.out.println("XYZ COMPANY Voucher Manager \n");
    do {
        System.out.println("Activities available: \n "
                + "1.Create a voucher \n "
                + "2.Print a voucher register \n "
                + "3.Issue checks");
        System.out.println("Enter number of choice (or zero to quit): ");
        choiceSelection = sc.nextInt();
    
        if (choiceSelection == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter purchase date (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
            sc.next();
            
            System.out.println("Enter amount: ");
            sc.nextDouble();
        
            System.out.println("Enter name of account to debit: ");
            sc.next();
            
            System.out.println("Enter name of vendor: ");
            sc.next();
            System.out.println();
            
        } 
        
        if (choiceSelection == 2) {
            System.out.println();
        } 
        
        if (choiceSelection == 3) {
            System.out.println("Enter number of voucher to pay: ");
            sc.nextInt();
            
            System.out.println("Enter payment date (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
            sc.next();
        }
        
    } while (choiceSelection != 0);
    
}
```

}

Initially, I had set new variables in the Driver to store the user input, however, I don't think that would work since those variables won't be "connected" to the variables on the VoucherClass, hence the scanner `sc` not having variables set to the left within the if statement.

I also tried calling my Voucher constructor method but I don't think I even did that right when I attempted to do so. If anyone can provide some insight on what I'm doing incorrectly, I would be most grateful.

A user commented that adding the assignment specs may be helpful, here is the sample session:

XYZ COMPANY Voucher Manager

Activities available:

1. create voucher
2. print voucher register
3. issue checks

Enter number of choice (or zero to quit): 4

Invalid choice. Try again.

Activities available:

1. create voucher
2. print voucher register
3. issue checks

Enter number of choice (or zero to quit): 1

Enter purchase date (dd/mm/yyyy): 17/08/2003

Enter amount: $123.45

Enter name of account to debit: tools

Enter name of vendor: Mack's Hardware

Activities available:

1. create voucher
2. print voucher register
3. issue checks

Enter number of choice (or zero to quit): 1

Enter purchase date (dd/mm/yyyy): 15/09/2003

Enter amount: $67.42

Enter name of account to debit: supplies

Enter name of vendor: ABC Company

Activities available:

1. create voucher
2. print voucher register
3. issue checks

Enter number of choice (or zero to quit): 2

Voucher Register:

voucher #1001   date: 17/08/2003   amount: $123.45

account: tools   vendor: Mack's Hardware

check #0   date: null

voucher #1002   date: 15/09/2003   amount: $67.42

account: supplies   vendor: ABC Company

check #0   date: null

Activities available:

1. create voucher
2. print voucher register
3. issue checks

Enter number of choice (or zero to quit): 3

Enter number of voucher to pay: 1000

No vouchers have that number.

Enter number of voucher to pay: 1001

Enter payment date (dd/mm/yyyy): 08/01/2004

Activities available:

1. create voucher
2. print voucher register
3. issue checks

Enter number of choice (or zero to quit): 2

Voucher Register:

voucher #1001   date: 17/08/2003   amount: $123.45

account: tools   vendor: Mack's Hardware

check #2001   date: 08/01/2004

voucher #1002   date: 15/09/2003   amount: $67.42

account: supplies   vendor: ABC Company

check #0   date: null

Activities available:

1. create voucher
2. print voucher register
3. issue checks

Enter number of choice (or zero to quit): 0

Comment: It might be an idea to post the assignment spec itself. You're going to want a `Voucher` class (note *singular*). I don't see that. You might want to model a `User` too. Avoid underscores in Java except in [constants](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)

Answer (score 1):

Collection like a list will be better approach to store Vouchers - btw. you can create list of 'Voucher' as a field in VoucherDriver. Then you dont need to initialize your Vouchers.

Assign scanner.nextLine/nextInt/nextString to variable (for validation e.q. Date if needed) and create new Voucher object using constructor at the end of if statement in main method. And add object to the list.

You don't need to use underscore in class fields if you are using this.